# Summing Configuration Question

Tags: amplifier, summing, operational-amplifier

I'm building the following circuit in a PCB . The purpose is simple, the first stage is a TIA amplifier that converts current into voltage and its working fine. The second stage, where the problem is at,  is to add dc bias to center the signal in 1.5V. 
[image: circuit]

The problem is that is not working as expected for low currents like in the magnitude of uA. In this magnitude of currents, where the signal voltage is low,  what is happening is that  DC bias stage is not centering at 1.5V but at a lower voltage, like 1.49/1.48V, probably has to do with the impedance from the TIA stage. The resistors have very low tolerance (0.1%), the 3.0V comes from a buffered voltage reference and all opamp's offsets are in the magnitude of uV.

Can i do something to improve this, have the resistors of the voltage divider some effect ?

Comment: Can you make the 2nd stage an inverting summing amplifier instead of non-inverting?

Comment: I can't, its already on a pcb. I was looking more in the approach of find an explanation for it and if the resistors values used in the voltage divider could improve somehow this problem, i could change them..

Comment: What kind of op amps are you using, you didn't draw the rails on the second amplifier and you don't describe what your ADC is

Comment: @laptop2d, in the post it says, "the resistors have very low tolerance (0.1%)"

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get past the horrible schematic to read the rest of the post

Comment: Although i will measure with an ADC, i'm using a bench-top multi-meter to do this measurements. I made a mistake in the supplies and made a new picture . The TIA opamp is OPA197 and the last one is AD8607. Sorry.